# SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused -> [with domain]

Tags: php, mysql, database

I tried different ports and restarting service mysql. All answerers that I found where for localhost and didn't helped me. Also tried different time zones thought it might be a problem. Don't know tho what to put under 'application address' maybe that is the problem. Thank you for answer.

```
<?php
ob_start();
session_start();

//set timezone
    date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Amsterdam');
    
    //database credentials
    define('DBHOST','servers_ip');
    define('DBUSER','root');
    define('DBPASS','pass');
    define('DBNAME','dbname');
    
    //application address
    define('DIR','https://domain/test/');//includes
    define('SITEEMAIL','noreply@domain.com');//i leave it like this
    
    try {
    
        //create PDO connection
        //
        $db = new PDO("mysql:host=".DBHOST.";port=8889;dbname=AppDatabase".DBNAME, DBUSER, DBPASS);
        //
        //$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_SILENT);//Suggested to uncomment on production websites
        $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);//Suggested to comment on production websites
        $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
    
    } catch(PDOException $e) {
        //show error
        echo '<p class="bg-danger">'.$e->getMessage().'</p>';
        exit;
    }
    
    //include the user class, pass in the database connection
    include('classes/user.php');
    include('classes/phpmailer/mail.php');
    $user = new User($db);
    ?>
```

Comment: Could be an outbound firewall on the machine running PHP, or an inbound firewall on the machine running MySQL. Are they on different machines? Are they in different networks / hosting environments? It wasn't fully clear, from your description. Having said that, 8889 is an unusual port for a mysql server, normally it runs on 3306. Have you double-checked all the settings?

Comment: `//Suggested to uncomment on production websites`...absolutely not. You need to know if exceptions occur in your PDO code. But what you should do on a production website is turn off PHP's overall on-screen error reporting, and instead tell it to log all errors to a file on the server. What you should not do (or need to do), is catch the exception and echo it, like you're doing now. Let PHP take care of it itself. Only catch exceptions if you need the code to carry on in some way after the exception has occurred - and even then, you should log them to a file instead of echoing them.

Comment: `Don't know tho what to put under 'application address'`...ok but that wouldn't be relevant to the problem with your MySQL connection - those variables are not used anywhere in the PDO code (as you can hopefully see for yourself).